# Как обратиться к ресурсу указав имя в виде строки?

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать анимированную икноку в трее. В Ресурсы добавил кратинки. Изменить иконку я могу так:

```
NotifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources._1;
```

Но я хочу изменение сделать в цикле с задержкой времени. У меня вопрос - как обратиться к ресурсу указав имя его в строке. Что-то вроде такого:

```
NotifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.["_1"]; //Псевдокод
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3621/SystemTrayNotifyIcon-with-Event-Generator ?

Comment: Выходит так, что в папку с установочными файлами мне нужно будет поместить все картинки или в другое место. но хотелось бы именно из ресурсов.

Comment: `(MyClass)Properties.Resources.GetObject("_1")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если посмотреть код в Resorces.Designer.cs, то там можно увидеть следующее

```
internal static System.Drawing.Icon _1 {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("_1", resourceCulture);
                return ((System.Drawing.Icon)(obj));
            }
        }
```

а также

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Возвращает кэшированный экземпляр ResourceManager, использованный этим классом.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("YourProject.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }
```

, а значит вам поможет такой код

```
NotifyIcon.Icon = (Icon)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_1");
```